# Is there any equivalent of jQuery slice() method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, ecmascript-6

Im looking for an equivalent `slice()` method in javascript. What could the equivalente of this jQuery code line in Javascript, with `ES6+`, in the shortest way possible?

```js
$("#myDiv .btn").slice(0,3).addClass("active");
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv">
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
  <button class="btn">4</button>
  <button class="btn">5</button>
  <button class="btn">6</button>
  <button class="btn">7</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `.slice()` **is** JavaScript; it's an Array method that jQuery copies.

Comment: The *equivalent* method in js is `.slice()` - it's not the *same* method, but it does the same thing. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without `.slice()` by modifying the selector to use [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child). This will allow you to select the first `n` elements. To select multiple elements you can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), which will give you back a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), that you can then iterate over using the [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) method, and then add your class to using [`classList.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add)

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#myDiv .btn:nth-child(-n+3)").forEach(
  elem => elem.classList.add("active")
);
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
  <button class="btn">4</button>
  <button class="btn">5</button>
  <button class="btn">6</button>
  <button class="btn">7</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, along with @mplungjan´s answer, this is one of the easiest to read and write. Sadly it´s still a pain ass to me in comparison to jQuery. Too verbose :(

Comment: @SilverSurfer I suppose that's one of the advantages of using jQuery haha. Maybe one day we'll be able to write the above line of code in a more compact way. I think creating a helper function would definitely be the way to go if you need to write this multiple times.

Comment: @SilverSurfer You can add `const $ = selector => [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)];` if you want to shorten your vanilla code to `$("#myDiv .btn").slice(0,3).forEach()` then you only have a little more than jQuery

Answer (score 3):

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("#myDiv .btn")]
  .slice(0, 3)
  .forEach(el => el.classList.add("active"))
```

is easier to read that the other suggestions here in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want this implementation in plain javascript? Because `.slice` is built-in method for array in JS, refered to this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("#myDiv .btn"), 0, 3).forEach((el) => {
  el.classList.add("active")
})
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
  <button class="btn">4</button>
  <button class="btn">5</button>
  <button class="btn">6</button>
  <button class="btn">7</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll("#myDiv .btn")].slice(0, 3).forEach(el => 
  el.classList.add("active"))` is easier to read in my opinion

Comment: @mplungjan sure it is